# synchronizing with source node id

Tags: synchronization, symmetricds

I would like to know how to do a sync through source_node_id through columms transforms.
X The table will update a record in table y, and I want it to update the record that it is (identified by source_node_id)

```
id | name | source_node_id
 1 |  a   | 3
 2 |  a   | 5
```

record in the table x (source_node_id = 3) to update the record id = 1.

tx

Comment: Are `source_node_id` equal to the `EXTERNAL_ID` of the target DB having the table `y`?

Comment: sorry, could specify?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [loading filters](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.5/html-single/user-guide.html#data-load-filter). They can be used at the target db to customize the population of the table `y`.